# Why VAE doesn't work for image reconstruction?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytorch, autoencoder, generative-adversarial-network

I use VAE to reconstruct images. For the first experiment I use VAE to reconstruct MNIST images and it works properly as expected. But using VAE to reconstruct CIFAR-10 and other RGB images, I get in the output something like "noise". The code below:

***Download data***

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((32, 32)), transforms.ToTensor()])

train_data = datasets.CIFAR10(root='data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)

test_data = datasets.CIFAR10(root='data', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
```

***Define Encoder&Decoder***

```
import torch.nn as nn

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim # latent space size
        hidden_dims = [32, 64, 128, 256, 512] # num of filters in layers
        modules = []
        in_channels = 3 # initial value of channels
        for h_dim in hidden_dims[:-1]: # conv layers
            modules.append(
                nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Conv2d(                    
                        in_channels=in_channels, # num of input channels 
                        out_channels=h_dim, # num of output channels 
                        kernel_size=3, 
                        stride=2, # convolution kernel step
                        padding=1, # save shape 
                    ),
                    nn.BatchNorm2d(h_dim),  
                    nn.LeakyReLU(), 
                )
            )
            in_channels = h_dim # changing number of input channels for next iteration

        modules.append(
            nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=1), # changing the kernel size, because  size of the array (2*2)
                nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
                nn.LeakyReLU(),
            )
        )
        modules.append(nn.Flatten()) # to vector, size 512 * 2*2 = 2048
        modules.append(nn.Linear(512 * 2 * 2, latent_dim)) 

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(*modules)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        return x


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super().__init__()

        hidden_dims = [512, 256, 128, 64, 32] # num of filters in layers
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features=latent_dim, out_features=512) 

        modules = []
        for i in range(len(hidden_dims) - 1): # define ConvTransopse layers
            modules.append(
                nn.Sequential(
                    nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                        in_channels=hidden_dims[i],
                        out_channels=hidden_dims[i + 1],
                        kernel_size=3,
                        stride=2,
                        padding=1,
                        output_padding=1,
                    ),
                    nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_dims[i + 1]),
                    nn.LeakyReLU(),
                )
            )

        modules.append(
            nn.Sequential(
                nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                    in_channels=hidden_dims[-1],
                    out_channels=hidden_dims[-1],
                    kernel_size=3,
                    stride=2,
                    padding=1,
                    output_padding=1,
                ),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_dims[-1]),
                nn.LeakyReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(in_channels=hidden_dims[-1], out_channels=3, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
                nn.Sigmoid(),
            )
        )

        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(*modules)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear(x) # from latents space to Linear 
        x = x.view(-1, 512, 1, 1) # reshape
        x = self.decoder(x) # reconstruction
        return x
```

***Define extra functions and reassign a VAE Encoder***

```
torch.manual_seed(42)

class VAEEncoder(Encoder):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        if latent_dim % 2 != 0: # check for the parity of the latent space
            raise Exception("Latent size for VAEEncoder must be even")
        super().__init__(latent_dim)


def vae_split(latent):
    size = latent.shape[1] // 2 # divide the latent representation into mu and log_var
#     mu = latent
#     log_var = latent
    mu = latent[:, :size] 
    log_var = latent[:, size:]  
    return mu, log_var


def vae_reparametrize(mu, log_var): 
    sigma = torch.exp(0.5 * log_var) #0.5 * log_var ???
    z = torch.randn(mu.shape[0], mu.shape[1]).to(device)
    return z * sigma + mu 


def vae_pass_handler(encoder, decoder, data, *args, **kwargs): 
    latent = encoder(data) 
    mu, log_var = vae_split(latent) 
    sample = vae_reparametrize(mu, log_var) 
    recon = decoder(sample)
    return latent, recon



def kld_loss(mu, log_var): 
    var = log_var.exp()
#     kl_loss = torch.mean(-0.5 * torch.sum(1 + log_var - mu ** 2 - var, dim=1), dim=0)
    kl_loss = 0.5 * torch.mean(torch.sum(mu ** 2 + var - log_var - 1., dim=-1))
#     The same result
    return kl_loss

def vae_loss_handler(data, recons, latent, kld_weight=0.005, *args, **kwargs):
    mu, log_var = vae_split(latent)
    kl_loss = kld_loss(mu, log_var)
    bce_loss = F.binary_cross_entropy(recons, data)
    loss = kld_weight * kl_loss + bce_loss
    return kl_loss, bce_loss, loss # add bce loss(reconstruction)
```

***Define models, cuda etc***

```
import torch.optim as optim
from itertools import chain


torch.manual_seed(42)

latent_dim = 100

learning_rate = 1e-4
encoder = VAEEncoder(latent_dim=latent_dim*2)
decoder = Decoder(latent_dim=latent_dim)

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available else 'cpu'
encoder = encoder.to(device)
decoder = decoder.to(device)

optimizer = optim.Adam(
    chain(encoder.parameters(), decoder.parameters()), lr=learning_rate
)
```

***Define train function***

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

def train(
    enc,
    dec,
    loader,
    optimizer,
    single_pass_handler,
    loss_handler,
    epoch,
    log_interval=500,
):

    for batch_idx, (data, lab) in enumerate(tqdm(loader)): 
        batch_size = data.size(0)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        data = data.to(device)
        lab = lab.to(device)
        
        latent, output = single_pass_handler(encoder, decoder, data, lab) # reconstructed image drom decoder 

        kl_loss, bce_loss, loss = loss_handler(data, output, latent) # compute loss
#         loss = loss_handler(data, output, latent)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % log_interval == 0:
            print(
                "Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]".format(
                    epoch,
                    batch_idx * len(data),
                    len(loader.dataset),
                    100.0 * batch_idx / len(loader),
                ).ljust(40), 
                "Loss: {:.6f}".format(loss.item()),
                "BCELoss: {:.6f}".format(bce_loss.item()),
                "KL_Loss: {:.6f}".format(kl_loss.item()),
            )
```

***Training***

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    train(
        enc=encoder,
        dec=decoder,
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loader=train_loader,
        epoch=i,
        single_pass_handler=vae_pass_handler,
        loss_handler=vae_loss_handler,
        log_interval=450,
    )
```

***I train almost 100 epochs and KL loss inreases while BCELoss decreases.***

[image]
[image]

---

***KL loss and BCELoss does not change if compare the first or second epoch and the last***
I can not figure out, why I do not get satisfying result?

```
encoder = encoder.eval()
decoder = decoder.eval()
```

***Want to return construction images***

```
def run_eval(
    encoder,
    decoder,
    loader,
    single_pass_handler,
    return_real=True,
    return_recon=True,
    return_latent=True,
    return_labels=True,
):

    if return_real:
        real = []
    if return_recon:
        reconstr = []
    if return_latent:
        latent = []
    if return_labels:
        labels = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (data, label) in enumerate(loader):
            if return_labels:
                labels.append(label.numpy())
            if return_real:
                real.append(data.numpy())
         
            data = data.to(device)
            label = label.to(device)
            rep, rec = single_pass_handler(encoder, decoder, data, label)
            
            if return_latent:
                latent.append(rep.cpu().numpy())
            if return_recon:
                reconstr.append(rec.cpu().numpy())

    result = {}
    if return_real:
        real = np.concatenate(real)
        result["real"] = real.squeeze()
    if return_latent:
        latent = np.concatenate(latent)
        result["latent"] = latent
    if return_recon:
        reconstr = np.concatenate(reconstr)
        result["reconstr"] = reconstr.squeeze()
    if return_labels:
        labels = np.concatenate(labels)
        result["labels"] = labels
    return result
```

***Start***

```
run_res = run_eval(encoder, decoder, test_loader, vae_pass_handler)
```

***Plot manifold***

```
plot_manifold(run_res['latent'], run_res['labels'])
```

[image]

***I got this picture, I suppose it is not normal, because using KL-divergence we want to make our classes as clasters. Apllying this code on the MNIST data I get***

[image]

***Visualize reconstruction images***

And I got this picture...

```
visualize(run_res['reconstr'], run_res['labels'], num_imgs=16)
```

[image]

[image]

Why does it happen? I make a wrong VAE? Although this model, this code for MNIST data works not so bad, but for RGB images, I get nothing

Comment: TL;DR, kindly read [ask]. Regards.

Comment: TL - transfer learning, DR - ??? Could you attach links on this terms and how to use them,

Comment: TL;DR = "too long; didn't read". The question is too long, read [how to ask questions from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The images you are using are repressenting objects and place with much more complicated structures, thus it is more complicated to make the network converge in general.

Comment: The image after VAE generated is blured(since VAE mechanism ), if you need more clear image, you should try other model, e.g. VQ-VAE.